# Найти максимум в последовательности

Tags: java, arraylist

мне нужна помощь. Вводится последовательность, состоящая из целых чисел. Найти наибольшее среди них.
Входные данные:

**3**

**1 2 3**

Выходные данные:

**3**

В программе нельзя использовать [](обычные массивы), нужно пользоваться ArrayList.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как мне сделать ввод количества элементов, а также сами элементы.
Вот моя программа:

```
public class ArrayList1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <String> list;
        list = new ArrayList <String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        
        Collections.max(list);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воодим число `n` с помощью `Scanner`. Потом `n` раз вводим нужное нам число. И в итоге выводим самое большое.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(Collections.max(list, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот оно как! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста.....